# PHP table pass to a var in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have this PHP code and I am trying to alert a table that receives its values via sql.
Here's my code:

```
    <script src="jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    function bus(x){
        alert("Row index is: " + x.value);
    }
    </script> 
    $sql="SELECT  ID, NOME, CPF FROM cadastro WHERE NOME LIKE '%" . $name .  "%'"; 
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $ID =$row['ID'];
                $NOME=$row['NOME'];
                $CPF=$row['CPF'];
    echo '<table style="width:100%">';
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th> ID </th>";
    echo "<th> NOME </th>";
    echo "<th> CPF </th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo '<tr style="cursor: pointer;">';
    echo "<td onclick='bus(" . $ID . ")' class='tab'>" . $ID . "</td>";
    echo "<td onclick='bus(" . $ID . ")' class='tab'>" . $NOME . "</td>";
    echo "<td onclick='bus(" . $ID . )' class='tab'>" . $CPF . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
```

I need to get the value from the table and serve it to a javascript function.

Comment: alert("Row index is: " + x); no need of .value

Comment: Could you elleborate more on your question? what are you getting from this code, an error or what?

Comment: The alert shows that the value is undefined

Comment: I need the value of the first collumn

Comment: undefined because a `<td>` does not have a value attribute

Comment: How i get the value of the php that i receive? Because in the html table shows the value.

Comment: try x.text() to return the text content of selected elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one error. `onclick` is passing the ID, so the following code will do exactly what you need:

```
<script>
function bus(x){
    alert("Row index is: " + x);
}
</script>
```

I removed the `.value` from your javascript.

```js
function bus(x){
alert("Value is " + x);
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td onclick="bus(44)">44</td>
<td onclick="bus(44)">Lorem</td>
<td onclick="bus(44)">ipsum</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I need the ID in alert, but i don't receive him. The alert shows "undefined"

Answer (score 1):

If x is a Number, then `x.value` will give you undefined and you should just use:

`alert("Row index is: " + x);`

To get the value of the column, you could pass `this` to the function instead of the id and then get the `innerHTML`:

`<td onclick="bus(this)" class="tab">column 1</td>`

```
function bus(elm){
    alert(elm.innerHTML);
}
```

```js
function bus(elm) {
  alert(elm.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="bus(this)" class="tab">column 1</td>
    <td onclick="bus(this)" class="tab">column 2</td>
    <td onclick="bus(this)" class="tab">column 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case x is not an object, just a plain value so:

```
alert("Row index is: " + x);
```

gl, pb